# SQL IN or EXISTS clause issue

Tags: sql, plsql, subquery

I have two separate queries that I'd like to combine but I'm struggling to get the result I'd like.  One summarizes all the values in the table and another selects duplicate rows based on the most recent date.

A shortened version of the first query is:

```
SELECT a.PLANT_NO "PlantNumber", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR' THEN -a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV 
                ELSE a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV END) "KeepWholeResidueMMBtu", 
       SUM(a.ETH_APPLIED_POP_PCT + a.ISO_APPLIED_POP_PCT  + 
           (CASE WHEN a.PLANT_NO = '002' THEN a.ALTLIQ_APPLIED_POP_PCT ELSE 0 END)
          )/100 "NGLPOPPaymentPercent"
FROM GAS_STMT a 
INNER JOIN SETTLE_SUMMARY c
   ON CASE WHEN SUBSTR(a.TRNX_ID,1,1) = '-' 
           THEN SUBSTR(a.TRNX_ID, 2, LENGTH(a.TRNX_ID)) 
           ELSE CAST(a.TRNX_ID AS VARCHAR2(100)) 
      END = c.TRNX_ID
  AND a.MTR_NO||a.MTR_SFX = c.MTR_NO||c.MTR_SFX
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.PROD_DT, 'YYYY')  >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36), 'YYYY') 
  AND a.STATUS_UNIT_TM_CD = 'M' 
GROUP BY a.PLANT_NO
ORDER BY a.PLANT_NO
```

The other query is used to filter out four transactions based on the most recent transaction date.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM GAS_STMT a,
     (SELECT MTR_NO,MTR_SFX,TRNX_ID,REC_STATUS_CD,MAX(ACCT_DT) ACCT_DT
      FROM GAS_STMT
      WHERE REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR'
      GROUP BY MTR_NO, MTR_SFX, TRNX_ID, REC_STATUS_CD
      HAVING COUNT(TRNX_ID) > 1) b
WHERE a.MTR_NO = b.MTR_NO
  AND a.TRNX_ID = b.TRNX_ID AND a.REC_STATUS_CD = b.REC_STATUS_CD
  AND a.ACCT_DT = b.ACCT_DT
```

I would think that I could use where `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` to have the first query sum everything except for those four records excluded in the second query.
Using `EXISTS` I get the same result as the first query by itself and using `NOT EXISTS` I get no results.  When I use `IN` I get a sum of the excluded records which is the opposite of what I want.

Is there a good way to do this in PL/SQL?  I'm confused that I'm not getting any records for the `NOT EXISTS` query.

Example of first query results:

> 1. **Plant_No** - **Sum**
> 2. 002  - 100
> 3. 450  - 50
> 4. 500  - 50

Example of second query results:

> 1. **Trnx_ID** - **Plant_no** - **KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV**
> 2. 1234  - 002  - -.99
> 3. 1235  - 002  - -.99

Intended result:

> 1. **Plant_No** - **Sum**
> 2. 002  - 98.02
> 3. 450  - 50
> 4. 500  - 50

Comment: Why are you talking about (Oracle) PL/SQL when your second query is using SQLServer-specific name-quoting characters (ie. `[]`)?

Comment: Also, the last line of the second query reads: `AND a.ACCT_DT = b.ACCT_DTenter code here` - what additional code should be entered instead of `enter code here`?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was working in Management Studio for part of it.  There isn't any additional code at the end of that.

Comment: Does the second query return the four records you want to exclude, or all records *except* the four that you want to exclude? (From the way it's coded, it looks like the former, but from your description *"The other query is used to filter out four transactions based on the most recent transaction date."*, it looks like the latter.)

Comment: The second query returns the four records I want to exclude.  I should have filled out the example data to also show 1236, 002, -.99 and 1237, 002,-.99.  Sorry again for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *exclude* the records returned by the second query, try:

```
SELECT a.PLANT_NO "PlantNumber", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR' THEN -a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV 
                ELSE a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV END) "KeepWholeResidueMMBtu", 
       SUM(a.ETH_APPLIED_POP_PCT + a.ISO_APPLIED_POP_PCT  + 
           (CASE WHEN a.PLANT_NO = '002' THEN a.ALTLIQ_APPLIED_POP_PCT ELSE 0 END)
          )/100 "NGLPOPPaymentPercent"
FROM GAS_STMT a 
INNER JOIN SETTLE_SUMMARY c
   ON CASE WHEN SUBSTR(a.TRNX_ID,1,1) = '-' 
           THEN SUBSTR(a.TRNX_ID, 2, LENGTH(a.TRNX_ID)) 
           ELSE CAST(a.TRNX_ID AS VARCHAR2(100)) 
      END = c.TRNX_ID
  AND a.MTR_NO||a.MTR_SFX = c.MTR_NO||c.MTR_SFX
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MTR_NO,MTR_SFX,TRNX_ID,REC_STATUS_CD,MAX(ACCT_DT) ACCT_DT
           FROM GAS_STMT
           WHERE REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR'
           GROUP BY MTR_NO, MTR_SFX, TRNX_ID, REC_STATUS_CD
           HAVING COUNT(TRNX_ID) > 1) b
   ON a.MTR_NO = b.MTR_NO 
  AND a.TRNX_ID = b.TRNX_ID 
  AND a.REC_STATUS_CD = b.REC_STATUS_CD 
  AND a.ACCT_DT = b.ACCT_DT
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.PROD_DT, 'YYYY')  >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36), 'YYYY') 
  AND a.STATUS_UNIT_TM_CD = 'M' 
  AND b.MTR_NO IS NULL
GROUP BY a.PLANT_NO
ORDER BY a.PLANT_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Join b from the second query on to the first query the same way that the second query does it i.e.

```
inner join (SELECT MTR_NO,MTR_SFX,TRNX_ID,REC_STATUS_CD,MAX(ACCT_DT) ACCT_DT
  FROM GAS_STMT
  WHERE REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR'
  GROUP BY MTR_NO, MTR_SFX, TRNX_ID, REC_STATUS_CD
  HAVING COUNT(TRNX_ID) > 1) b 
 on a.MTR_NO = b.MTR_NO
   AND a.TRNX_ID = b.TRNX_ID AND a.REC_STATUS_CD = b.REC_STATUS_CD
   AND a.ACCT_DT = b.ACCT_DT
```

that way you get everything from the first query but only from the rows that would show up on the second query